# D3 Hierarchical Bar Chart - Change X and Y axis values

Tags: javascript, python, d3.js, bar-chart, data-visualization

Currently, in case of D3 Hierarchical Bar Chart, Each blue bar represents a folder, whose length encodes the total size of all files in that folder (and all subfolders). I want that the blue bar should encode the **length** (not size) of the total no. of items within it. For example, in below example if I click on 'vis', it has 7 items within it. Therefore, the the length of the bar for 'vis' should be 7. Similarly for all items in all folders. Here's the link - https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1283663

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

rect.background {
  fill: white;
}

.axis {
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
}

</style>
<title>D3</title>
</head>
<body>
 <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script>
var margin = {top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 40, left: 50},
    width =  window.innerWidth - margin.left - margin.right-100,
    height =  window.innerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom-100;

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var barHeight = 20;

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["steelblue", "#ccc"]);

var duration = 750,
    delay = 25;

var partition = d3.layout.partition()
    .value(function(d) { return d.size; });

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "background")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .on("click", up);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + height + ")")
    .append("line")
    .attr("x1", "100%");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis");

d3.json("https://jsonblob.com/api/f577d19c-0f2b-11e7-a0ba-09040711ce47", function(error, root) {
  if (error) throw error;

  partition.nodes(root);
  y.domain([0, root.value]).nice();
  down(root, 1000);
});

function down(d,i) {
  if (!d.children || this.__transition__) return;
  var end = duration + d.children.length * delay;

  // Mark any currently-displayed bars as exiting.
  var exit = svg.selectAll(".enter")
      .attr("class", "exit");

  // Entering nodes immediately obscure the clicked-on bar, so hide it.
  exit.selectAll("rect").filter(function(p) { return p === d; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Enter the new bars for the clicked-on data.
  // Per above, entering bars are immediately visible.
  var enter = bar(d)
      .attr("transform", stack(i))
      .style("opacity", 1);

  // Have the text fade-in, even though the bars are visible.
  // Color the bars as parents; they will fade to children if appropriate.
  enter.select("text").style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);
  enter.select("rect").style("fill", color(true));

  // Update the x-scale domain.
  y.domain([0, d3.max(d.children, function(d) { return d.value; })]).nice();

  // Update the x-axis.
  svg.selectAll(".y.axis").transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .call(yAxis);

  // Transition entering bars to their new position.
  var enterTransition = enter.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .delay(function(d, i) { return i * delay; })
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + barHeight * i * 2.5 + "," + 0 + ")"; });

  // Transition entering text.
  enterTransition.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition entering rects to the new y-scale.
  enterTransition.select("rect")
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(!!d.children); });

  // Transition exiting bars to fade out.
  var exitTransition = exit.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .style("opacity", 1e-6)
      .remove();

  // Transition exiting bars to the new y-scale.
  exitTransition.selectAll("rect")
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); });

  // Rebind the current node to the background.
  svg.select(".background")
      .datum(d)
    .transition()
      .duration(end);

  d.index = i;
}

function up(d) {
  if (!d.parent || this.__transition__) return;
  var end = duration + d.children.length * delay;

  // Mark any currently-displayed bars as exiting.
  var exit = svg.selectAll(".enter")
      .attr("class", "exit");

  // Enter the new bars for the clicked-on data's parent.
  var enter = bar(d.parent)
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + barHeight * i * 2.5 + "," + 0 + ")"; })
      .style("opacity", 1e-6);

  // Color the bars as appropriate.
  // Exiting nodes will obscure the parent bar, so hide it.
  enter.select("rect")
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(!!d.children); })
    .filter(function(p) { return p === d; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the y-scale domain.
  y.domain([0, d3.max(d.parent.children, function(d) { return d.value; })]).nice();

  // Update the y-axis.
  svg.selectAll(".y.axis").transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .call(yAxis);

  // Transition entering bars to fade in over the full duration.
  var enterTransition = enter.transition()
      .duration(end)
      .style("opacity", 1);

  // Transition entering rects to the new y-scale.
  // When the entering parent rect is done, make it visible!
  enterTransition.select("rect")
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .each("end", function(p) { if (p === d) d3.select(this).style("fill-opacity", null); });

  // Transition exiting bars to the parent's position.
  var exitTransition = exit.selectAll("g").transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .delay(function(d, i) { return i * delay; })
      .attr("transform", stack(d.index));

  // Transition exiting text to fade out.
  exitTransition.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Transition exiting rects to the new scale and fade to parent color.
  exitTransition.select("rect")
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .style("fill", color(true));

  // Remove exiting nodes when the last child has finished transitioning.
  exit.transition()
      .duration(end)
      .remove();

  // Rebind the current parent to the background.
  svg.select(".background")
      .datum(d.parent)
    .transition()
      .duration(end);
}

// Creates a set of bars for the given data node, at the specified index.
function bar(d) {
  var bar = svg.insert("g", ".x.axis")
      .attr("class", "enter")
          .attr("transform", "translate(15,0)")
       .selectAll("g")
          .data(d.children)
        .enter().append("g")
         .style("cursor", function(d) { return !d.children ? null : 
    "pointer"; })
          .on("click", down);

      bar.append("text")
          .attr("x", barHeight / 2)
          .attr("y", height + 10)
          .attr("dy", ".35em")
          .style("text-anchor", "start")
          .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
          .attr("transform", "rotate(45 " + (barHeight / 2) + " " + (height + 
    10) + ")")

      bar.append("rect")
          .attr("width", barHeight)
          .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
          .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); });

      return bar;
    }

    // A stateful closure for stacking bars horizontally.
    function stack(i) {
      var y0 = 0;
      return function(d) {
        var tx = "translate(" + barHeight * i * 1.5 + "," + y0 + ")";
        y0 += y(d.value);
        return tx;
      };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bar.append("rect")
          .attr("width", barHeight)
          .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
```

the **d.value** defines the number that is used to display.
if you need something else, pick the property of the object (d) that is relevant to you.

Comment: Adding this to the code, doesn't display anything on the graph. Can you have a look again?

Comment: what is you object composed of? what properties does it have? and what is the one you want to use? If the one you want to use is called 'size' then replace `d.value` with `d.size`

Comment: My JSON object is exactly the same like given in the example. I just want that the values on the axis should not be the sum of size of all folders and subfolders. But it should be the length of the items within it.

Comment: You can use the json given in the example to replicate this.

Comment: and you can use your debugger to trace the code and figure what should be there. SO is not here to debug your code for you. Just give you advice on what to do to fix it yourself.

Comment: Thank you. I am new to using D3 and I was only seeking help to know how can this be done. How can those numbers be changed to the length of the items in the immediate next folder? Thanks anyways.

Comment: I looked at the data. there is 'size' but it's the size of the file. if you need to number of items, you need to write a function to COUNT the children in each folder.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your support.

Comment: from what i can see in the API doc of the hierachy cluster stuff, you need to update the 'sum' function
https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy#hierarchy

Comment: I see. This needs some very good D3 knowledge. If you can try your hands on this, i will really appreciate it. But this information was really helpful.